# @Cacheable with Spring 3.1

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, caching, ehcache

I am using **@Cacheable** with **Spring 3.1**. I little bit confused with value and key mapping parameters in Cacheable.
Here is what I am doing:

```
@Cacheable(value = "message", key = "#zoneMastNo")
public List<Option> getAreaNameOptionList(String local, Long zoneMastNo) {
//..code to fetch data form database..
return list;
}

@Cacheable(value = "message", key = "#areaMastNo")
public List<Option> getLocalityNameOptionList(String local, Long areaMastNo) {
//..code to fetch data form database..
return list;
}
```

What happening here, second method is dependent on selected value of first method,
but issue is suppose when I pass **zoneMastNo = 1 and areaMastNo = 1** then second method returns first methods result.
Actually, I have lots of services hence, I am looking to use common value for cacheable for specific use cases.
Now my questions are:

- How can I solve this issue?
- Is it good idea that use cacheable for every services?
- After specified time will cache completely remove from memory without
  using @CacheEvict ?

Answer (score 2):

> - How can I solve this issue?

I assume `zoneMastNo` and `areaMastNo` are completely different keys, by which I mean `List<Option>` for `zoneMastNo` = `1` is not the same as `List<Option>` for `areaMastNo` = `1`. This means you need **two caches** - one keyed by zone and the other by area. However you are explicitly using only one cache named `message`. Quoting [*29.3.1 @Cacheable annotation*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable):

> ```
> @Cacheable("books")
> public Book findBook(ISBN isbn) {...}
> ```
>
> In the snippet above, the method findBook is associated with the cache named `books`.

So if I understand correctly, you should basically use two different caches:

```
@Cacheable(value = "byZone", key = "#zoneMastNo")
public List<Option> getAreaNameOptionList(String local, Long zoneMastNo)
//...
@Cacheable(value = "byArea", key = "#areaMastNo")
public List<Option> getLocalityNameOptionList(String local, Long areaMastNo)
```

Also are you sure these methods won't have a different result depending on `local` parameter? If not, what is it used for?

---

> Is it good idea that use cacheable for every services?

No, for the following reasons:

- some methods are just fast enough
- ...and caching introduced some overhead on its own
- some services call other services, do you need caching on every level of hierarchy
- caching needs memory, a lot of it
- cache invalidation is hard

---

> After specified time will cache completely remove from memory without using @CacheEvict ?

That totally depends on your cache implementation. But every sane implementation has such an option, e.g. EhCache.

Answer (score 0):

question 3: 
  it depends on your cache expiration configuration. if you use ehcache, change the settings in ehcache.xml.

Comment: that means if I define in ehcache.xml as: timeToIdleSeconds="180" timeToLiveSeconds="180" overflowToDisk="true" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="180" it will remove cached value after 3 minutes? Also can you shear some links that explain the purpose of attributes of <cache> elements